# Add text to Core Data entry

Tags: core-data, text

I have a core data model set up and I am using a text entry box to record data. My code looks like this:

```
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSNumber *timetickNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timeTick];
[newDevice setValue:timetickNumber forKey:@"name"];
[newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
[newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];
```

For the second entry title 'version' I am trying to add text in front of what ever is typed. For example, it would say 'This is' and then show the text that was typed next to it. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are trying to concatenate a string. Maybe something like this:

```
NSString *versionString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is: %@", self.companyTextField.text]
```

The value of versionString would be "This is: [insert text from text field here]".

Then to save to core data you would just do:

```
[newDevice setValue:versionString forKey:@"company"];
```

Comment: Your BOSS! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to mix formats and data. (Remember the Model-View-Controller pattern?) If you store "This is ", it will quickly become redundant and would anyway not display correctly in different languages. This is quite problematic design from many perspectives.

Instead, you should store the value in Core Data as you do in your code. If you need to *display* this data, e.g. in a `UILabel` you can add whatever text you need (and you can change it later without much ado).

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is %@.", device.company];
```

or even better

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", 
    NSLocalisedString(@"This is ", "string to present the company"), 
    device.company];
```